# Не понятно почему при разных приведениях типов Dev C++ или выдает, или не выдает ошибку

Tags: c++, ооп, devc++

Фрагменты моего класса Int, где n - единственный член класса:

```
Int checkit(long double ans)
        {
            if (ans < -2147483648 || ans > 2147483648)
            {
                cout << "Overloaded! Error! ";
                exit(1);
            }
            return Int(int(ans));
        }

operator int()
        {
            return n;
        }

Int operator+(Int b)//первый вариант
        {
            return checkit(static_cast<long double>(n) + static_cast<long double>(b));
        }

Int operator+(Int b)//второй вариант
        {
            return checkit(long double(n) + long double(b));
        }
```

При верхнем примере перегрузки оператора компилятор ошибку не выдаёт, но при втором выдаёт ошибку перед long double(n) - 'expected primary expression before long'

Comment: заключите `long double` в скобки

Comment: `overflow != overload`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что название типа во втором варианте содержит пробел, что недопустимо при использовании такого синтаксиса. Используйте алиас для целевого типа.

Comment: А если коротко, то что такое этот алиас?

Comment: @ЯнИльясов Альтернативное имя для типа, которое дается директивой `using` или (в С) `typedef`.